# Copy files from server 1 to another server 2 (Jenkins installed in Server 2, Pull or listening method)

Tags: jenkins, server, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Say server-A, has files or versions and that I need to migrate periodic basis say every 15 mins to another server-B.
Note: Jenkins installed in Server-B, so its a pull method not pushed or publish method.

Comment: Define OS. And clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 3 steps -

1. Authorise SSH keys, make sure your jenkins user public key on server B exists in `authorized_keys` of the `remote_user` on server A.
2. Use rsync to pull the files from remote i.e Server A -

   ```
   rsync -chavzP --stats -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/server_B_pvt.key" remote_user@serverA:/from/dir/ /to/dir/
   ```
3. Setup a cron for Jenkins user every 15 mins -

   ```
   */15 * * * * rsync -chavzP --stats -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/server_B_pvt.key" remote_user@serverA:/from/dir/ /to/dir/
   ```

Your Jenkins server i.e server B will not be able to pull files periodically.

If you are using a version control, you can integrate it with CI(Jenkins) & define/configure job to `Build Periodically` with value - `*/15 * * * *` .